# JDeveloper not allowing to create a new WebTier project

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I've downloaded the latest and greatest version of Oracles JDeveloper 12.2.
I want to create a new Web Project, but every possible options is "greyed out", so  I cannot create it: 
[image: JDev Create Projekt]

When downloading JDev, I was asked to download 2 Files (one Exe, one Zip). I can't find an instructure what to do with the zip file. Maybe this contains the extension. I don't know.

Do you have an idea? thanks ,e .

Answer (score 1):

Create a new empty Java Client Project using JDeveloper
Right Click the Select Project New --> From Gallery -->WebTier-->Servlets-->HTTP Servlet
You should now be able to create new Servlets Web Tier Project